# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013: Cannot Create a new Asp.Net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

File -> New -> Website -> ASP.NET Web Forms Site -> OK

```
Configuring IIS Express failed with the following error:

Filename: redirection.config
Error: Cannot read configuration file
```

So I've tried several solutions. I checked and already have IIS Express installed. I also am running as admin. I don't know what else to do and googling just tells me to turn it on (it's checked in my tools options)

File -> New -> Project -> ASP.NET WebApplication -> Web Forms Template -> Ok

```
Unspecified error(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))
```

Are these related? Why can't I do anything related to ASP? My Documents folder is not encrypted.

**Result:**
I eventually got a new computer where this problem did not occur, so I did not personally solve this problem. Sorry.

Comment: What Windows Version do you use ?

Comment: Windows 8. and yep I know there are related posts. None of them have really solved my problem so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same issue. Here's what worked for me.

- Close Visual Studio.
- Navigate to your Documents folder, and then the IISExpress subfolder.
- Rename the "config" folder to something else. "configBACKUP" will do.
- Open Visual Studio and try to create a new ASP.NET project.

IISExpress will create the necessary .configs in a brand new "config" folder.

Comment: This is a late update but better late than never. This solution did not work for me back when I tried it. I did not think to come back and update because I was still scouring for answers. This ended up not being what fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue due to having IIS Express 10.

Resolved by clicking Repair on it in Programs & Features.
Took 5 seconds and it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

User\Documents\IISExpress\config files try to uncheck Read Only property

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked fine after I went to IISExpress folder Documents\IISExpress\config and unchecked the "encrypt content to segure data" cause by default win 8.1 will encrypt it.